# Bulk Video Upload with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, networking, post, upload, afnetworking

I am attempting to get AFNetworking (1.x) to batch upload some long videos to my server, however when I use the standard functions the application's memory spikes to 400MB and then quits.

```
NSMutableArray *requests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[MyServerClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:URL parameters:@{ @"json": jsonString } constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:mediaData name:idString fileName:fileName mimeType:mimeType];
            }];

[request setTimeoutInterval:10800];

[requests addObject:operation];


[[MYServerClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:requests   progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

        NSLog(@"Number - %d %d", numberOfCompletedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);

    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"Completion block");
    }];
```

The MyServerClient is a pretty standard subclass of AFHTTPClient:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    [self.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

    return self;
}
```

I'm guessing the memory crash might have something to do with the application failing to throttle the amount of concurrent operations, but in light of setting setMaxConcurrentOperationCount, I'm not sure.  Does anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

**EDIT:** My guess is that the crash is due to the app attempting to load the media into memory prior to attaching it to the multipart request.  Is there some way to stream the upload from disk within this POST usage scenario?

Comment: send video in chunks..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I'm planning on adding this method in the future, but uploading them whole shouldn't result in the above behavior, should it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue, the following appears to fix my crash:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[MyServerClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:URL parameters:@{ @"json": jsonString } constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileURL:mediaURL name:idString error:nil];
            }];
```